# Typescript difference between setting variables in body vs constructor

Tags: typescript

This has probably been asked before as its a simple question, but googling things similar to the title hasn't got me anywhere. I'm not sure how to word the question properly, so if someone could let me know the right terms and a resource that answers the question that would be nice too.

In TypeScript, what is the difference between assigning to variables in the body of the class, like this:

```
export class Test1 {
  var1 = 5;
}
```

And assigning the values in the constructor, like this:

```
export class Test2 {
  constructor() {
    this.var1 = 5;
  }

  var1: number;
}
```

Is it a better practice to use one over the other? Are there certain situations in which it is necessary to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the generated javascript code (with no minification):

```
var Test1 = (function () {
    function Test1() {
        this.var1 = 5;
    }
    return Test1;
}());

var Test2 = (function () {
    function Test2() {
        this.var1 = 5;
    }
    return Test2;
}());
```

It's just the same.

As long as your instance variables are simply assigned hard coded primitive types you can safely assign them in the body of the class. If you have complicated logic or if you need one variable to be initialized before intializong another one it's better to do it in the constructor for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The emitted code for a property initializer is just an assignment at the start of the constructor, so these are exactly equivalent in terms of runtime characteristics.

It's probably best to only user the initializer syntax when there aren't dependencies between properties. TypeScript won't enforce any particular ordering, or re-order the initializers for you, so writing the initialization code in the constructor when there is a mandatory ordering will make it clearer that the members shouldn't be re-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between those two , as whatever you add as a variable id went into constructor , if you see its java script conversion you will understand it better.

[Example in Typscript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%09greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09greeting1%3A%20string%3D%22delta%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B)

and what is better , you should assign the variable in constructor it will be runtime assignable and better to understand as well.